# Reading unencrypted Derby/JavaDB database without knowing username and password

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Given:

Unencrypted Derby/JavaDB database on the local disc that has username and password defined.

Questions:

- Is it easily possible to read the content of that database without knowing username and password?
- Is it easily possible to modify the content of that database without knowing username and password?

Are there any tools already available for doing this? I could not easily find any. Or would this task require a tedious reverse-engeneering of the Derby sources first?

Comment: On a hunch I'd say it's probably quite easy. It's not like they would go through a lot of trouble trying to make it secure, considering the use cases (and a local attack vector).

Comment: I have no idea what specific question you are asking, but the Derby Security Manual is a good place to start: https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/security/index.html